# Stuck at ip_tables (C) 2000-2002 Netfilter Core team when install

Tags: release-juno, boot, usb, live-installation

[image]

Stuck when installing, how i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with deleting efi folder, try this if nomodeset is not working